# Catch unit test library linking error

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch-unit-test

I am trying to use CATCH unit test suite linked below.
https://github.com/philsquared/Catch

However, I cannot succeed to make it right.
The main.cpp and test.cpp are as follows.

```
//main.cpp
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN 
#include "catch.hpp"

//test.cpp
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("TESTTest", "") {
    CHECK(1 != 2 );
}
```

When this two files are located in the same folder, I could get a desired result.
However, I moved the `test.cpp` to the subdirectory named `test`. It does not work anymore as expected but generates linking errors.

My cmake setting is described below.

```
project(catchTest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

file(GLOB_RECURSE INCS "./*.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp ${INCS})

include_directories(.)
```

`file(GLOB_RECURSE INCS "./*.cpp")` was added to include every cpp source files located in the subdirectories. and `include_directories(.)` was included to let them know the definition of `catch.hpp`.

I am pretty shure I've done something wrong but I don't know how to fix it. 
Please advise me to solve this problem.

It was run on Windows, compiled using mingw gcc-4.9.1 and generated by cmake ninja generator.

EDIT : I added the first few lines of error messages.

FAILED: cmd.exe /c cd . && C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe     CMakeFiles/catchTest.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/catchTest.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/catchTest.dir/test/testTest.cpp.obj  -o catchTest.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcatchTest.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd .
CMakeFiles/catchTest.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Catch::getResultCapture()'

CMakeFiles/catchTest.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here

Comment: It seems to be an issue with an multible defined symbol, see for instance:'multiple definition of `Catch::getResultCapture()'

Comment: @KimKulling That is right. However, I do not know the catch internal and so do not know how to make it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CMakeLists.txt is wrong, it includes main twice. If you change the add_executable-statement like this it works for me:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp test.cpp )
```

Hope that helps.

Kim

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the right catch.hpp. In the repository there are two different includes with the same name: One in include and one called single_include. Please ensure that you are using single_include.

Comment: I downloaded the file in this link: http://builds.catch-lib.net/integration/latest/catch.hpp Can you check this is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

When you see something like linking error from a header file library such as catch, it means you have set the include path incorrectly.

Use `single_include` not `include`.